# Handling varying number of result sets in Petapoco or Dapper?

Tags: dapper, petapoco

I have used `QueryMultiple` before for handling multiple result sets, but I knew the exact number of result sets being returned.  In this case, when I call a stored proc with `QueryMultiple`, the number of result sets returned varies.  Is it possible to handle this in PetaPoco or another orm such as Dapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper's `QueryMultiple` method returns a `GridReader`; a `GridReader` has a `.IsConsumed` property that should change to `true` when you've read all the available result sets, so that might work:

```
using(var reader = conn.QueryMultiple(...)) {
    do {
        var data = reader.Read<...>().AsList();
        // ...
    } while(!reader.IsConsumed);
}
```

Alternatively, Dapper has an `ExecuteReader` method that just does the "pack the parameters and invoke step", and a `GetTypeDeserializer` method that exposes just the "materialize a row into an object" code, so you could manually combine those, i.e.:

```
using(var reader = conn.ExecuteReader(...)) {
    do {
        var parser = SqlMapper.GetTypeDeserializer(...);
        while(reader.Read()) {
            var obj = parser(reader);
            // ...
        }
    } while(reader.NextResult());
}
```

(I don't know much about petapoco, sorry)

Comment: Thanks Marc, is one faster than the other?

Comment: @xaisoft feel free to time it and let me know :)

Comment: Marc, I went ahead with QueryMultiple.  It works great. Thanks again